# When do we use in Javascript object in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using asp core web api, and I would like to understand what is meaning of sending a
JavaScript object without serilaize it on a jQuery ajax request ?

For example:

```
var data = {firstName: '123', lasName: '' }
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,       
        success:  callback
  });
```

When  would I prefer to send?
javascript object

Does it reflected by the method type? (POST/GET)

I've search over the net and for my understanding we send Javascript object on GET method because jQuery ajax will turn it to key pair value. Is it the only reason?

Comment: jquery sends strings with XHR. If what you give it isn't a string, jquery will convert it to one using $.param. it's rather simple and [well documented](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery serializes it for you.  By default, it will send it as `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Agreed. The data is "converted to a query string, if not already a string." [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, `jQuery` will automatically convert the object to a URL-encoded parameter string.

One of the main benefits of doing this is that it will encode the values properly. A number of characters require special encoding, and if you simply concatenate variables like:

```
var data = "firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname;
```

you could have problems if the names contain any of those characters. The proper way to write this is:

```
var data = "firstname=" + encodeURIComponent(firstname( + "&lastname=" + encodeURIComponent(lastname);
```

Using an object saves you from having to worry about this, jQuery ensures that it's done properly.